# Azure WAF rule blocks image upload request from application but allows from PostMan

Tags: .net, postman, azure-waf

**Environment:** We have a Windows application installed in the customer agents machine, a feature of this application is to upload images to the server via http post. These requests go through Azure Gateway and WAF is enabled with OWASP3.2 all rules enabled.
Request details are displayed in Fig-1 data is sent as MultipartFormData.

**Problem Statement:** These requests are blocked by WAF when our Windows application sends the request but the same requests are allowed when posted from PostMan. The RULE 200003 [Multipart Request Body Strict Validation.] is blocking the request and the reason for the block is [Equal 1 at MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR.]. For reference below Fig-2.

[Fig-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfRVE.png)
[Fig-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJJgp.png)

**Things tried to resolve**

1. Used the query generated from PostMan in a console application
2. Used fiddler to see the request format how PostMan is sending and modified the console app request to the same request format
3. Referred 2 URLs - a)[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322174/waf-200003-multipart-request-body-strict-validation), b)[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1092665/access-denied-with-code-403-(phase-2)-match-of-eq) where they say it is a bug from the Microsft side but it's working via PostMan

**Question:** Why is WAF allowing requests from PostMan and not from Visual Studio via a console app or an installed Windows application?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!

Comment: @NaveenSharma  I think this is a programming question. Could you please reopen that? Because after hosting an application and image upload is happening through Postman, we should be able to upload images using client code. We are also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Shishir Sasal could you please share the solution if the issue is resolved?

Comment: @HrishikeshTT No it is not yet resolved, I will be trying it out with a test web application instead of a console application, post man acts as a web app I believe.

Comment: @NaveenSharma Ok will do.

Comment: @ShishirSasal could you please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926645/httpcontent-boundary-double-quotes
It resolved our problem.